Efficient Computation of convolution-like expression
Let $p\left(z_i \mid x_i\right)$ for $i=1, \ldots, m$ be some probabilities, where $x_i, z_i \in\{0,1\}$. I want to efficiently compute the following:
\begin{align*}
\nu\left(z_1, \ldots, z_m\right)=\sum_{x_1, \ldots, x_m} \prod_{i=1}^m p\left(z_i \mid x_i\right) \mu\left(x_1, \ldots, x_m\right)
\end{align*}
I know that convolutions can be computed efficiently with FFT in $O\left(m 2^m\right)$. Is there a way to compute $\nu\left(z_1, \ldots, z_m\right)$ with similar computational complexity?

Specifically, $p\left(z_i \mid x_i\right)$ does not depend on $i$ and is given as follows:
$p(z \mid x)=\left{\begin{array}{ll}1-q, & (z, x)=(0,0) \ q, & (z, x)=(1,0) \ 1 / 2, & (z, x)=(0,1) \ 1 / 2, & (z, x)=(1,1)\end{array}\right.$
